# Select a = 1 in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

how can translate this SQL query in MongoDb Query ? Is it possible ?

```
Select 
       a = 1, 
       field1 
from 
       TableName 
where 
       aField = myValue
```

Thanks guys

Comment: It is with the aggregation framework by using the $project opertor but since `a` is not used I am unsure why you use this SQL query

Comment: Why not just add the field on the client?

Answer (score 0):

Adding static field may not be possible with find() , using aggregate gives you same output 
as your SQL query . Solution is little bit dumb .

```
db.TableName.aggregate( {$match: { aField : myValue   }},
         { $project : {_id:0, field1 :1, a: {$add: [1]} } } )
```